# Filter lines according to a percentage

Tags: awk, filter, sed, command-line

I need to filter some files in which the "Identities" are greater than 90%.

**Example file**

```
>EAW73057.1 ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 4, isoform 
CRA_b, partial [Homo sapiens]
Length=1203

 Score = 2445 bits (6337),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 1174/1174 (100%), Positives = 1174/1174 (100%), Gaps = 0/1174 (0%)
>NP_005493.2 phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA1 [Homo sapiens]
 O95477.3 RecName: Full=Phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA1; AltName: 
Full=ATP-binding cassette sub-family A member 1; AltName: 
Full=ATP-binding cassette transporter 1; Short=ABC-1; Short=ATP-binding 
cassette 1; AltName: Full=Cholesterol efflux regulatory 
protein [Homo sapiens]
 BAB63210.1 ABCA1 [Homo sapiens]
Length=2261

 Score = 2246 bits (5819),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 1150/2284 (50%), Positives = 1511/2284 (66%), Gaps = 81/2284 (4%)
```

The result should be like this:

```
>EAW73057.1 ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 4, isoform 
CRA_b, partial [Homo sapiens]
Length=1203

 Score = 2445 bits (6337),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 1174/1174 (100%), Positives = 1174/1174 (100%), Gaps = 0/1174 (0%)
```

I edited my code following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228067/filtering-the-lines-which-are-greater-than-a-percentage-value/1228087#1228087):

```
awk '{RS="Identities"; FS=" "; original_block=$0; gsub(/\(|\)|%|,/,""); if ($5 >= 99) print original_block}' my_file.txt
```

Got this:

```
   >EAW73057.1 ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 4, isoform 
CRA_b, partial [Homo sapiens]
Length=1203

 Score = 2445 bits (6337),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.

 = 1174/1174 (100%), Positives = 1174/1174 (100%), Gaps = 0/1174 (0%)
>NP_005493.2 phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA1 [Homo sapiens]
 O95477.3 RecName: Full=Phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA1; AltName: 
Full=ATP-binding cassette sub-family A member 1; AltName: 
Full=ATP-binding cassette transporter 1; Short=ABC-1; Short=ATP-binding 
cassette 1; AltName: Full=Cholesterol efflux regulatory 
protein [Homo sapiens]
 BAB63210.1 ABCA1 [Homo sapiens]
Length=2261

 Score = 2246 bits (5819),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.

 = 1150/2284 (50%), Positives = 1511/2284 (66%), Gaps = 81/2284 (4%)
```

Another attempt was:

```
awk '{RS="Identities"; FS=" "; gsub(/\(|\)|%|,/,""); if ($5 >= 99) print }' my_file.txt
```

And I get this:

```
   >EAW73057.1 ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 4, isoform 
CRA_b, partial [Homo sapiens]
Length=1203

 Score = 2445 bits (6337),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 = 1174/1174 100 Positives = 1174/1174 100 Gaps = 0/1174 0
>NP_005493.2 phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA1 [Homo sapiens]
 O95477.3 RecName: Full=Phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA1; AltName: 
Full=ATP-binding cassette sub-family A member 1; AltName: 
Full=ATP-binding cassette transporter 1; Short=ABC-1; Short=ATP-binding 
cassette 1; AltName: Full=Cholesterol efflux regulatory 
protein [Homo sapiens]
 BAB63210.1 ABCA1 [Homo sapiens]
Length=2261

 Score = 2246 bits (5819),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 = 1150/2284 50 Positives = 1511/2284 66 Gaps = 81/2284 4
```

My filtering strategy is not working. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `>` is used solely for denoting where block is starting, you are always interested in 1st percentage and percantages are always given as integer (e.g. `90%` but not `90.1%`), then I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
>EAW73057.1 ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 4, isoform 
CRA_b, partial [Homo sapiens]
Length=1203

 Score = 2445 bits (6337),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 1174/1174 (100%), Positives = 1174/1174 (100%), Gaps = 0/1174 (0%)
>NP_005493.2 phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA1 [Homo sapiens]
 O95477.3 RecName: Full=Phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA1; AltName: 
Full=ATP-binding cassette sub-family A member 1; AltName: 
Full=ATP-binding cassette transporter 1; Short=ABC-1; Short=ATP-binding 
cassette 1; AltName: Full=Cholesterol efflux regulatory 
protein [Homo sapiens]
 BAB63210.1 ABCA1 [Homo sapiens]
Length=2261

 Score = 2246 bits (5819),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 1150/2284 (50%), Positives = 1511/2284 (66%), Gaps = 81/2284 (4%)
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">";FPAT="[0-9]+%"}int($1)>90{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
EAW73057.1 ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 4, isoform 
CRA_b, partial [Homo sapiens]
Length=1203

 Score = 2445 bits (6337),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 1174/1174 (100%), Positives = 1174/1174 (100%), Gaps = 0/1174 (0%)
```

Explanation: Firstyle I inform GNU `AWK` that `>` is used as record separator and fields are like 1 or more digits followed by `%` sign. Then for each record I exploit `int` function to get value, in this case `100` from `100%`. Then I print if value is greater than 90. Keep in mind assumptions described earlier and if you wish to use my code test it with other data.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. With any `awk` this should work.

```
awk '
found && /Identities/{
  gsub(/\(|\)|%|,/,"",$4)
  if($4+0>90){ print val }
  found=val=""
  next
}
/^>/ { found=1 }
found{
  val=(val?val ORS:"") $0
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples and with GNU `awk`, please try following code.

```
awk -v RS=' Identities = [0-9]+/[0-9]+ \\([0-9]{1,3}%\\)[^\n]*' '
RT{
  split(RT,arr)
  gsub(/\(|\)|%|,/,"",arr[4])
  if(arr[4]+0>90){ print $0 RT }
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***Explanation of 1st code:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
found && /Identities/{        ##Checking if found is SET and line contains Identities then do following.
  gsub(/\(|\)|%|,/,"",$4)     ##Globally substituting ( ) % and  , with NULL in 4th field.
  if($4+0>90){ print val }    ##Checking if 4th field is greater than 90 then printing val.
  found=val=""                ##Nullifying val and found here.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^>/ { found=1 }              ##Checking if line starts from > then setting found to 1.
found{                        ##Checking if found is SET then do following.
  val=(val?val ORS:"") $0     ##Creating val which has current line values(keep concatenating).
}
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks! The first code didn't print the "Identities line" but the second code worked really well!